# ES6 Destructuring assignment without declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's the difference between the following syntax? Will the second one generate global variables?

```
// 1. use let or cont
let [a, b] = [1, 2]

// 2. without using let or const 
[a, b] = [1, 2]
```

Provide me any official reference would be appreciate.

Comment: Are you having some particular problem with one or the other of those statements? What documentation have you looked at so far?

Comment: It's my bad, I also assumed without let will result in global variable, however, I might did wrong way to check the assumption and caused I believed it might behavior differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example defines the variables within block scope.

The second example defines the variables globally.

Comment: seems not, I tried both chrome and node, the a and b is not global

Comment: @YueGu That is not correct. `{[a, b] = [1, 2]}`  will define `a` and `b` globally `console.log(a) // 1`. `{let [a, b] = [1, 2]}` will define `a` and `b` only within the block scope `console.log(a) // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Comment: @YueGu If `a` and `b` are not otherwise explicitly declared, then in "strict" mode that would be an error, but in non-strict mode the variables would be *implicitly* declared to be global.

Comment: It's my bad, I also assumed without let will result in global variable, however, I might did wrong way to check the assumption and caused I believed it might behavior differently.

Answer (score 0):

[***See the MDN pages***.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_separate_from_declaration)

I'd assume that no declaration type would result in the array being initialized like a `let`, based on what I'm reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring).

`let` is block scoped and `var` is function scoped, perhaps you could check this yourself?